# PDFCreator V2.1 C++ COM startup

Tags: c++, pdf, mfc, pdf-generation

I'm trying to use the new PDFCreator (V2.1). clsPDFCreator is no longer there, and all the examples I've found in my searches use that old system.

They supply examples in other languages, but none in C++ (MFC Windows). I think that once I have established the connection to PDFCreator I can follow the examples in the other languages.

A fragment of the old version:

```
CComPtr<PDFCreator::_clsPDFCreator> pdfObject;
HRESULT hr = pdfObject.CoCreateInstance(L"PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator");
pdfObject->cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup", 1);
```

and I've been trying to guess what the new version equivalent should be, but with no success. For example:

```
CComPtr<PDFCreator::IPDFCreator> pdfObject;
HRESULT hr = pdfObject.CoCreateInstance(L"PDFCreator.IPDFCreator");
```

compiles but hr signals a failure...

hr gives me "incorrect interface string" (I'm translating from italian): hr = 0x800401f3 Stringa dell'interfaccia non valida. –

PDFCreator makers have now told me documentation and proper support for COM will only be available in V2.2

Comment: Isn't that class name now `PDFCreatorBeta.PDFCreator` like shown in [`this topic`](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/2.1/en/com-interface/user-manual/basics/printers/) (I don't get why *beta* in that name though) ? `</wild guess>`

Comment: Please update your question with information about the specific error code you get. @TLama: From [COM Interface](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/2.1/en/com-interface/): *"The COM interface still has beta status and it will change with the next releases."*

Comment: hr gives me "incorrect interface string" (I'm translating from italian): hr = 0x800401f3 Stringa dell'interfaccia non valida.

Comment: I've just tried "PDFCreatorBeta.PDFCreator" with no luck. What I really need is a code sample of someone who's already done this. I hope I'm not the first to try it!

Comment: *"no luck"* is not an error description. Please update your question with relevant information (hr of your original code, other interface strings you have used, error values for **every** failure).

Comment: I've already described the error in the comment above, complete with error number.

Comment: Comments aren't part of a question. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30951613/edit) your question to include **complete** information.